# How to synchronize apis to external system

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed WSO2 API manager4.0.0 All-in-one on my vms.
They are working fine.
Now ,there is a external system of my company , wants to get all apis from wso2apimanager, the apis will list in their system, and they want to invoke wso2 apis from their system.
Anyone can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You can export APIs using the apictl command line tool as in [1]. But these projects are only readonly from the WSO2 API Manager. You can use the Swagger definitions and host them in a 3rd party system.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/ci-cd-with-wso2-api-management/